# Bonjour Programming on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, bonjour

i am just try to implement the tutorial from [here](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44126/0/page/2) but i have problem in `-(void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)service {}`
 this method [image] how can i remove these error plz help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i will suggest you this tutorial for Bonjour Networking:-http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/bonjour_network_server_for_iphone

Comment: but i want to know that how can i send request to other iOS device to connect.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a header file, make sure you included all the right ones.

Comment: @borrrden ya u r right u just post your answer here i will accept it.

Comment: @SmartWork Krishnabhadra's answer is better because he actually found which header to include ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

struct sockaddr_in is declared in [netinet/in.h](http://freebsd.active-venture.com/FreeBSD-srctree/newsrc/netinet/in.h.html)

```
struct sockaddr_in {
   u_char   sin_len;
   u_char   sin_family;
   u_short  sin_port;
   struct   in_addr sin_addr;
   char sin_zero[8];
};
```

and inet_ntoa as

```
char    *inet_ntoa __P((struct in_addr)); /* in libkern */
```